# Is there an R function that detects and deletes ALL duplicates in a date using group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to detect date duplicates, then remove *all* the duplicates from the df within groups, preferable using `group_by()`. I have tried `n=n()`and `duplicated()` to no avail.

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this;

```
UID<-1:10
Group1<-c(rep("Slytherin", 2), rep("Ravenclaw", 3), rep("Hufflepuff", 3), rep("Gryffindor", 2))
Group2<- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5))
Date<-as.Date(c(rep("2021-01-01", 3), "2021-02-09", rep("2021-03-12", 2), "2021-05-06", "2021-10-05", rep("2021-10-11", 2)))
Value<-sample(1:100, 10)
df<-data.frame(UID, Group1, Group2, Date, Value)
df
```

My expected output would be just UID's 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, and 8.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group1, Group2, Date) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  filter(n == 1) %>% 
  select(-n)

# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   Group1, Group2, Date [6]
    UID Group1     Group2 Date       Value
  <int> <chr>      <chr>  <date>     <int>
1     3 Ravenclaw  A      2021-01-01    75
2     4 Ravenclaw  A      2021-02-09    70
3     5 Ravenclaw  A      2021-03-12   100
4     6 Hufflepuff B      2021-03-12    67
5     7 Hufflepuff B      2021-05-06    43
6     8 Hufflepuff B      2021-10-05    17
```

Comment: Why not just filter directly on `n() == 1` - save creating then removing the variable?

Comment: You certainly could. It's just my habit to create these types of flags in a separate step.

Comment: This answer does exactly what I asked, detects as well as deletes the duplicates. The solution also works on my real dataset. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Update. thanks to thelatemail for clarification:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group1, Group2, Date) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1) 

    UID Group1     Group2 Date       Value
  <int> <chr>      <chr>  <date>     <int>
1     3 Ravenclaw  A      2021-01-01    44
2     4 Ravenclaw  A      2021-02-09    51
3     5 Ravenclaw  A      2021-03-12    52
4     6 Hufflepuff B      2021-03-12    40
5     7 Hufflepuff B      2021-05-06    88
6     8 Hufflepuff B      2021-10-05    14
```

I case you mean to remove all duplicated Dates, we could use `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1)
```

Comment: I assume they are wanting to remove duplicate dates within each `Group1 + Group2` group, given the requested output to keep rows 3-8. I.e. - `df %>% group_by(Group1, Group2, Date) %>% filter(n() == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This all hinges on we are counting duplicates at these column combination:
Group1, Group2, Date

```
# set as data.table
setDT(df)

# flag those with multiple rows
df[, dummy := .N, .(Group1, Group2, Date)]

# subset
df <- df[dummy == 1]

# remove dummy count col
df[, dummy := NULL]
```

Answer (score 0):

What columns are you trying to have in your output? If you are just looking for a few columns

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% distinct(Group1, Group2, Date)
```